# How to add data to specific user and show in specific page?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to add data according to user specific logged in. I am stucked in how to do that this is my code below.

## views.py [My actual code to add data]

```
def addintro(request):
        form = AboutForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AboutForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('addintro')

        total=About.objects.all()
        context = {
            'form':form,
            'total':total,
        }
        return render(request, 'Backend/aboutme/Intro/add-intro.html', context)
```

## I tried this method and it is working But I want to pass my form in this code.Can I pass my form in this code?

```
def addintro(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST['data']
        new = About(description=data, author=request.user)
        new.save()
        return render(request, 'Backend/aboutme/Intro/add-intro.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'Backend/aboutme/Intro/add-intro.html')
```

## forms.py

```
class AboutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = About
        widgets = {
            'description': SummernoteWidget(attrs={'summernote': {'width': '100%', 'height': '400px'}}),
        } 
        fields = '__all__'
```

## models.py

```
class About(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='+')
    description=models.TextField("Write About You",null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing what you want to ask, I assume according to your code, that your view is not showing you the form.

1) You're not passing any data to the `render` and therefore shows nothing.
2) When it gets a request different than POST, the form is not declared.
3) The form is called `AboutForm` not `About` as that is the model you're aiming to.

And it is always good to include a `form.is_valid()` check.

```
def addintro(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        newform = Aboutform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new = newform.save(commit=False)
            new.author = request.user
            new.save()
        # use redirect instead of render after form saved
        return redirect('Backend/aboutme/Intro/add-intro.html')
    else:
        new = AboutForm() #if request is not POST, pass empty form
    context = {
        'form' = form
        'content' = yourcontent #if your view want to pass extra content
    }
    return render(request, 'Backend/aboutme/Intro/add-intro.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. It is working now. I can now successfully see a logged in user specific page and specific data.Really thank you alot.

Comment: @Pankajkushwaha Grad to know it works, consider marking as answered

Comment: i need your help in django project, can you give some time to complete it.If you are free give me a message here [link](https://www.facebook.com/beinghunter1919)

Answer (score 0):

## Above mentioned problem is solved now. This is the working Code for me

```
def addintro(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            

    newform = AboutForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
                if newform.is_valid():
                    new = newform.save(commit=False)
                    new.author = request.user
                    new.save()
                return redirect('addintro')
            else:
                new = AboutForm()
        
            log_user=request.user
            total=About.objects.filter(author=log_user)
            context = {'new':new,'total':total}
            return render(request, 'Backend/aboutme/Intro/add-intro.html',context)*
```